# Ultra-low accuracy, the loss function converges to 2

Tags: matlab, mnist

The content of my experiment is a customized minst data set for classification. Each number from 0 to 9 has 50 pictures placed in a Minst folder. The name is like 7_13.bmp, which is the 13th picture of the number 7. I I used MATLAB to compile a convolutional neural network for classification, but the classification effect was not good. The accuracy on the test set was only 10%, and the loss function only converged to 2. This was still the case after I added regularization and preprocessing. Can you help me analyze it?

```
% 设置数据集路径

datasetPath = 'Mnist';

% 加载MNIST数据集

digitDataset = imageDatastore(datasetPath, ...

'FileExtensions', {'.bmp'}, 'LabelSource', 'foldernames');

% 自定义标签提取函数

digitDataset.Labels = categorical(cellfun(@(x) str2double(regexp(x, '(?<=\\)\d+(?=_\d+\.)', 'match', 'once')), digitDataset.Files));

% 将数据集划分为训练集和测试集

[trainData, testData] = splitEachLabel(digitDataset, 30, 20, 'randomize');

% 数据预处理

trainData.ReadFcn = @(filename)preprocessImage(filename);

testData.ReadFcn = @(filename)preprocessImage(filename);

% 定义卷积神经网络（CNN）模型

layers = [

imageInputLayer([28 28 1])

convolution2dLayer(5, 24, 'Padding', 0) % 卷积层

batchNormalizationLayer

tanhLayer

maxPooling2dLayer(2, 'Stride', 2)

fullyConnectedLayer(100) % 全连接层

tanhLayer() % 添加tanh激活函数

fullyConnectedLayer(10, 'Name', 'fc', 'WeightsInitializer', 'he', 'BiasInitializer', 'zeros') % 全连接层，使用softmax激活

softmaxLayer()

classificationLayer(); % 分类层

];

% 设置训练选项

options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...

'MaxEpochs', 20, ...

'MiniBatchSize', 64, ...

'InitialLearnRate', 0.002, ...

'Plots', 'training-progress');

% 训练CNN模型

net = trainNetwork(trainData, layers, options);

% 在测试集上评估模型

predictedLabels = classify(net, testData);

accuracy = sum(predictedLabels == testData.Labels) / numel(testData.Labels);

disp(['测试集准确率: ' num2str(accuracy * 100) '%']);

% 显示测试集中的一些图像及其预测标签

figure;

perm = randperm(numel(testData.Files), 25);

for i = 1:25

subplot(5, 5, i);

imshow(readimage(testData, perm(i)));

title(['Predicted: ' char(predictedLabels(perm(i)))]);

end

function img = preprocessImage(filename)

% 读取图像

img = imread(filename);

% 将图像归一化到 [0, 1] 范围

img = double(img) / 255;

end
```

I tried to increase the regularization term and modify the learning rate and the number of network layers, but the accuracy rate did not change significantly. I hope that the classification accuracy of this simple data set can be very high.